# Checking the dataframe records against Unique constraints of a sqlalchemy model

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy model and a pandas dataframe with few records which are supposed to be loaded into table represented by that sqlalchemy model. But before loading I need to check if all rows in dataframe satisfy 'UniqueConstraint'

My Model and dataframe are as follows:

*Model:*

```
class Flight(Base):
__tablename__ = 'flight'

flight_id = Column(Integer)
from_location = Column(String)
to_location = Column(String)
schedule = Column(String)
__table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('flight_id', 'schedule', name='flight_schedule'),)
```

*Dataframe:*

```
flight_id | from_location  | to_location |  schedule |  
   1      |   Vancouver    |   Toronto   |   3-Jan   |  
   2      |   Amsterdam    |   Tokyo     |   15-Feb  |  
   4      |   Fairbanks    |   Glasgow   |   12-Jan  |  
   9      |   Halmstad     |   Athens    |   21-Jan  |  
   3      |   Brisbane     |   Lisbon    |   4-Feb   |  
   4      | Johannesburg   |   Venice    |   12-Jan  |
```

In this case, the checker function should return false as 3rd & 6th records in dataframe violate uniqueconstraint (same flight can't be scheduled for 2 different routes at the same time). Any hints/solutions on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think need [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for check dupes per specified columns with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) for check at least one `True`:

```
print (df.duplicated(['flight_id', 'schedule']).any())
True
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.duplicated(['flight_id', 'schedule']))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```

And if you need filter problematic rows use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and parameter `keep=False` for return all dupes:

```
print (df[df.duplicated(['flight_id', 'schedule'], keep=False)])
   flight_id from_location to_location schedule
2          4     Fairbanks     Glasgow   12-Jan
5          4  Johannesburg      Venice   12-Jan
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.duplicated(['flight_id', 'schedule'], keep=False))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: @Wen - Yes, I released it, so quick remove comment :)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But, You should take sqlalchemy model into consideration. If my model constraints ever change, I should't always go and change my dataframe checker. your code will definitely work but only for an example scenario I described in the question.

Comment: @Kingz - Do you think exctract columns from `UniqueConstraint('flight_id', 'schedule',` and use it as parameter to `duplicated` function?

Comment: @Kingz ... your comment is a very important item to have included in your question. Also, one should not continually change table constraints as it can invalidate other rows. Constraints, keys, triggers, etc. should be set up once during database schema design stage before data population.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC `duplicated`

```
df.duplicated('flight_id',keep=False)
Out[473]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```

Or using `groupby`

```
df.groupby('flight_id').transform('nunique').gt(1).any(1)
Out[482]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```